# Neo4j.rb (8.0.11) + Resque : Input/output error @ io_write - <STDOUT>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, neo4j.rb

I have recently upgraded neo4j and I am getting issue in resque workers,

```
Exception
Errno::EIO
Error
Input/output error @ io_write - <STDOUT>
```

I am getting this issue and backtrace says its related to neo4j.rb `puts`

[Errno::EIO: Input/output error - <STDOUT>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23820469/errnoeio-input-output-error-stdout)

```
/home/ubuntu/staycircles-backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/neo4j-8.0.11/lib/neo4j/session_manager.rb:60:in `write'
/home/ubuntu/staycircles-backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/neo4j-8.0.11/lib/neo4j/session_manager.rb:60:in `puts'
/home/ubuntu/staycircles-backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/neo4j-8.0.11/lib/neo4j/session_manager.rb:60:in `puts'
/home/ubuntu/staycircles-backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/neo4j-8.0.11/lib/neo4j/session_manager.rb:60:in `block in wait_for_value'
```

**My current configration is**

```
neo4j version - 3.xx
neo4j.rb - 8.0.11
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I have the same problem using sidekiq and Neo4j: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43264757/sidekiq-broken-pipe-error.  Are you seeing this problem on Heroku, AWS, or some other platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try updating to `8.0.13` of the `neo4j` gem?

Answer (score 1):

The gem maintainers have released v `8.0.13`, which removes the puts statements.  Want to see if it fixes the issue on your end?

https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/releases/tag/v8.0.13

Comment: fixed my problem!