# Sidekiq Broken Pipe Error

Tags: amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq, foreman, neo4j.rb

I am attempting to migrate from Heroku to AWS, but my Sidekiq jobs keep failing with the following error:

`Errno::EPIPE: Broken pipe @ io_write - <STDOUT>`

I can successfully run jobs from the console using `perform_now`, and everything works just fine in Heroku, so I am presuming the issue lies somewhere with my AWS setup.  I have seen references to improper daemonization around Stack Overflow and Github but not sure how to solve the problem.

Right now I am launching my processes with the following command:

`foreman start -f Procfile -p 3000 -e $VAR_FILES &`

and I have tried the command both with and without the `&` at the end.

My Procfile looks like this:

`web: bundle exec puma -t 1:2 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-production}
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
log: tail -f log/production.log`

and I have also tried it like this, following the instructions here (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Logging#syslog):

`worker: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml 2>&1 | logger -t sidekiq`

My `sidekiq.yml` has `logfile` set to `./log/sidekiq.log`, which I believe is supposed to redirecting logs away from STDOUT anyway.

I have seen the discussion here (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/3188) and can verify that the `rails12factor` gem is not in my Gemfile.

But still the error persists...  Can anyone lend a hand?

UPDATE: I can finally get a stack trace and see it is coming from a `puts` statement inside of the Neo4j.rb gem:

`` 2017-04-07T15:46:53.553Z 697 TID-12a6r4 WARN: Errno::EPIPE: Broken pipe @ io_write - <STDOUT>
2017-04-07T15:46:53.553Z 697 TID-12a6r4 WARN: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/neo4j-c804cb33bef8/lib/neo4j/session_manager.rb:60:in `write'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/neo4j-c804cb33bef8/lib/neo4j/session_manager.rb:60:in `puts'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/neo4j-c804cb33bef8/lib/neo4j/session_manager.rb:60:in `puts' ``

But still not sure how I can mitigate the issue.  I have tried with `RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=enabled` both set and unset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke to the gem maintainers and they removed the puts statements in v `8.0.13`.  It fixed the problem for me!